# Error in using 'angular-route' or ever 'angular-ui-router'

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I am using 'angular-route' for routing, but when I pass the 'ngRoute' module in dependent modules list i am getting an

Error:- 
***Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=Error%3A%…127.0.0.1%3A52621%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A135) in angular.js:38***

Same is error arriving while using 'angular-ui-router'. I have properly passed the dependent module entry in modules list . Example:-

My app.js

1) when using 'angular-route'

```
define(['angular'], function(angular){
    return angular.module('MyApp',['ui.router']).
config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        $stateProvider
         .state('Home', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "views/home.html",
            controller: 'MyController'
         })
         .state('List',{
            url : "/list",
            templateUrl : "views/list.html",
            controller: 'MyController'
         })
    }); 
});
```

2) when using 'angular-ui-router'

```
    define(['angular'], function(angular){
     return angular.module('MyApp',['ngRoute']).
      config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider    
        .when('/',
            {
                controller: 'MYController',
                templateUrl: '/views/home.html'
            })
        .when('/list',
            {
                controller: 'MyController',
                templateUrl: '/views/list.html'
            })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
            });
        }); 
    });
```

I am not able to make out why is this error arriving, please help.

Answer (score 1):

You should define external module in the define function , like you did not define ui-router as well as ngroute in the define function of requirejs ..

Try doing :

```
define(['angular','uiRouter'], function(angular){
return angular.module('MyApp',['ui.router']).
```

Comment: After doing what you said i.e. adding the external module "uiRouter" in define function I am getting an error:- 

Uncaught Error: Invalid require call
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#requireargs

and previous error is coming as it is :- 

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=Error%3A%…127.0.0.1%3A55852%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

My main.js where i have used require.config to load all js and export modules is :-

http://pastie.org/10198002

Comment: I think you should define a baseurl  in your require.config


         `require.config(
         baseUrl: '<your current directory>'
         paths : {
             'angular' : '../bower_components/angular/angular.min',`
   
The 'paths:{}' , will be evaluated relative to the baseUrl ... Your angular error also points that your app is not able to find angular.js file , and the path to angular.js is defined in your require.config only ..